# Getting the albums from GraphObject and displaying them in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I managed to get the album data from Facebook using the GraphObject:

```
Request.ExecuteGraphPathRequestAsync (Session.ActiveSession, "/me/albums", this);
```

I get all the data of the albums like the album id, album name, count of photos etc as an InnerJSONObject:

```
Console.WriteLine("output = " + response.GraphObject.InnerJSONObject);
```

I get the output as an InnerJSONObject - as a string containing all of the data.

My question is, how do I parse that object in such a way that, I get separate fields like album id, name etc, for EACH album - which I can use to display the photos in my app.

Or, is there any direct method which builds the user's Facebook album page(including UI), using the FB id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation says (http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AOrg.Json.JSONObject), JSONObject is "a modifiable set of name/value mappings. Names are unique, non-null strings. Values may be any mix of Org.Json.JSONObject, Org.Json.JSONArray, Strings, Booleans, Integers, Longs, Doubles or JSONObject.Null. Values may not be null, Java.Lang.Double.IsNaN, Java.Lang.Double.IsInfinite, or of any type not listed here." so you can use it as any key / value object (eg: as a IDictionary)

But I think the best and easiest way is to deserialize the JSON object to a class. I mean, convert the JSONObject to string and then deserialize using JSON.NET (http://james.newtonking.com/json). Eg:

```
var data = response.GraphObject.InnerJSONObject;

// get json string
var dataString = data.ToString ();

// deserialize  it
var myAlbums = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyAlbums>(dataString);
```

- To obtain the "MyAlbums" class, you can create it using the album JSON string (dataString) and this wonderful tool http://json2csharp.com/